# Access SharePoint 2013 site from other Network

Tags: sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping, access, external-users

I have a SharePoint 2013 site on my Windows Server 2012 that is connected to a Virtual Network(INTERNAL) and I want to access my SharePoint site on another Computer that is connected to another Virtual Network(External)

Internal and External Virtual Network is connected to each other via Endian Firewall.

What do I need to configure on my SharePoint server, so other Computer from another network can access my SharePoint site?

I'm sorry I'm very new to SharePoint, please guide me.

PS : This is for testing only.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a host header- You have to setup a host header to your site. Then setup your domain to redirect to your Machine or you can map your Sharepoint Server IP to your host header in accessing machines host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host) for testing purpose

Allow anonymous access for your site collection.

Allow the port that your web app uses in your SharePoint Server firewall

Comment: Thank you @anbuj, follow up question, I setup DNS Server connected to External and named it webtest.com and I would like to make a A/AAA host www what IP add do I need to put on www? The IP of SharePoint Server?

Comment: Yes. with port.

Comment: where would I put the port? I already created a Public IP for my SharePoint Server, and put that IP on my new Host(A) www, my 2nd question now is about binding, i create a external URL http://www.test.com will i bind it on my default Site Binding on IIS Manager? that I will just put www.test.com on host name and IP address pointing to my public IP or pvt IP?